# jQuery Ajax with async: false and return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Im building a browser based application.
On window.load, i call a jquery AJAX GET function which is supposed to get me some gamedata from the server. 
Once the data is there, i parse this data into my javascript and build some stuff up.
For that reason, i set async to **false**.

Now looking at this function, i want to call another function on ajax.success, but i want to use the freshly returned data as well as the data that was sent to this very function as a parameter (from another async ajax call).
How can i do this ?
thanks

```
window.onload = function(){
    ajax.getFleets();
    ajax.getShips(fleets);
    manager.draw() // can only draw if both ajax functions have received data !)
}

getShips: function(fleets){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getGameData.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
            type: "ships"
            },      
        error: ajax.error,
        success: ajax.mergeData, //want to pass fleets and returnData to this function
        async: false
    });
},
```

Also, on a general note, using async: false is the correct approach for this, right ?

thanks,

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and anyway was never the correct approach to anything

Comment: The correct approach would be to use callbacks/promises and than call the code. Synchronous calls will lock up the browser and cause load times to be even longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) will pass your callback function the result of the AJAX request, so you can use a simple anonymous function to get both parts in. Let's say you have your callback function defined like this:

```
ajax = {};
ajax.mergeData = function(fleets, ajaxResult) { 
    console.log(fleets);
    console.log(ajaxResult);
};
```

You can define your callback function as:

```
function(result) { ajax.mergeData(fleets, result); }
```

Putting that all together, your getShips function will look like this:

```
ajax.getShips = function(fleets) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getGameData.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
            type: "ships"
            },      
        error: ajax.error,
        success: function(result) { ajax.mergeData(fleets, result); }
    });
};
```

---

To answer your second question: `async: false` is a deprecated option, so you can't rely on it to work. It will also lock up the browser until the server responds, which makes for a really bad user experience. It's far better to use callback functions or promises to carry out an action when your AJAX requests complete. [Here's a short summary of the promises concept](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html) that might be useful.

---

Which leaves the last, big question: how do we chain these calls together so `getShips()` depends on the result of `getFleets()`, and `manager.draw()` depends on both? With just two calls, you could get away with just using callbacks; `getShips`' success callback invokes `getFleets`, and `getFleets`' callback invokes `manager.draw`. This is the easiest way to get an A → B → C dependency chain working – but we could also use [jQuery's promises](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which might make our code easier to follow.

First, let's change `getFleets` to return the result of calling `$.ajax`:

```
ajax = {};
ajax.getFleets = function() { 
    return $.ajax({ /* Details elided here */ });
}
```

Next, let's update `getShips` to make an AJAX request for that data, and return a promise that *returns the combined data*:

```
ajax.getShips = function(fleets) { 
    return $.ajax({ /* Details elided again */ })
            .done(function(ajaxResult) { return mergeData(fleets, ajaxResult); });
 };
```

This is a bit trickier; `$.ajax` returns a promise that will eventually resolve to our ship data. When it does, we'll call the function in `.done` that returns the merged data. And that `.done` *also returns a promise* – so `getShips` is now returning a promise that will eventually return the merged data.

So now we can write our `window.onload` function to chain all these together, and only call `manager.draw` when all the data's available:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    ajax.getFleets()
        .done(ajax.getShips)
        .done(manager.draw);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to modify MY code above (edited) in a way that would allow it to work when both getFleets() and getShips() have their async: false removed, please ?
I cant wrap my head around callbacks for my code.
Note i dont mind the order, however, draw() can only be used once getFleets and getShips have data to return / parse.

Comment: I've extended my answer to talk about how this could work, with a short explanation of callbacks and a longer one about promises.